# chrome.tabs.query returns .url as undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Updated Issue: I can console.log any amount of tabs but no tabs have the url property.

[image: argh]

Original Problem that is solved:I cannot seem to get this very simple piece of code to work in background.js. I want to get access to the tabs but they always return as `object Object` for each tab.

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tab){
        alert(tab);
  });
```

[image: objects!]

I DO have tabs in my manifest file, but even without it doesn't make a difference. Personally  I think that it doesn't think it has the permissions to tabs but it does and my other permissions such as notifications & urls work fine. Thanks.

Comment: `alert` is not a good debugging tool. It converts everything to strings. Use `console.log`.

Comment: My console is empty if I use console.log.

Edit: Sorry, after checking the background.js's console it is still undefined.

Comment: Do you get any results if you supply some query information (e.g. `{ active: true }`)?

Comment: Then inspect what exactly `tab[0]` is, so that you know what properties you can access. Are you sure your extension has the  'tabs' or 'webNavigation' permissions?

Comment: Console.log was undefined. But now its working =/ Seems your tip about alert was the main issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ha, I was starting to get very confused - glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Aha, I was so frustrated, I've been trying to get the extension API working for ages and have been alerting all my tests. Had no idea it converting things to strings so thanks for that heads up.

That said, the .url of the tabs are still undefined. Any ideas there? (In the console there isn't even a url property)

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have an extension that works on another developer's chrome, but not mine...same code and manifest.

Comment: I thought this could be due to another chrome extension, however this works on another pc that syncs my chrome extensions

Comment: This was cleared up for me by a computer restart (not even a Chrome restart worked).

Comment: I have this same problem as OP and so far it seems to happen on unsecure webpage tabs (http, not https). Can anyone confirm? Will keep testing.

Answer (score 6):

After adding the tabs permission in manifest.json you need to remove and re-add the extension in order for it to take account of the new permission.

Comment: God bless your soul!

Answer (score 5):

`chrome.tabs.query` actually returns an array of [Tab objects](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) (which is why you are seeing `[object, Object]`. Try doing something like:

```
alert(tab[0].url);
```

And see if it displays something that you are expecting.

Comment: That gives me undefined, as does tab[0].url (as chrome.tabs.query gives me an array I thought that would give me something)

Comment: @Slappybag Sorry, will adjust my answer to reflect the array part. You're getting undefined with `tab[0].url`?

Comment: Yes, I am getting undefined with `tab[0].url`

Comment: @Slappybag And the error is telling you that the object at that location is undefined or the property of that object is undefined?

Comment: Yeah this is still happening. I can console.log all the tabs through querying. But any variation of tab.url or tab[0].url is undefined.

In the console there isn't even a url property for any tabs.

Comment: @Slappybag What are the properties of the object?

Comment: Properties in image of original question but the list is; 
0: Object,
**active:** true,
**highlighted:** true,
**id:** 138,
**incognito:** false,
**index:** 0,
**pinned:** false,
**selected:** true,
**status:** "complete",
**windowId:** 1

Comment: @Slappybag And just to double check, you definitely do have `tabs` in your permissions list? And I'm assuming your other objects look the same as that one?

Comment: Yup, I've got `"tabs"` and even added `"webNavigation"` to my permissions list to make sure. All tabs look like that at least, even if I specifically reference one by id using `chrome.tabs.get`. I feel like I'm missing something very simple or my permissions aren't working.

Comment: @Slappybag Ha, hmm okay, I'll think on it a bit - that seems indicative of a permissions thing but clearly isn't. Have you tried reloading it completely from scratch with those permissions? Since `chrome.tabs.get` doesn't work either, it just seems like something is funky (I think you're right about the permissions).

Comment: I can query for the URL though, and thats all I need to do. (In my extension I need to see if tabs with certain URLs are open, not find out the URLs of open tabs) So lets call this solved. (Even if it isn't really)

Comment: @Slappybag Hmm, well I'll continue to think over it and see if anything springs to mind - agree that it must be something simple we're both overlooking :)

Comment: @Slappybag:Share your code of manifest file and background page by editing your question, it is entirely related to permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add "tabs" to the permissions array in your manifest.json, otherwise you will not be able to see the url of the tabs.

Comment: Which is easy to screw up if you copy a `permissions` snippet from the docs and paste it at the end of the JSON, effectively hiding your earlier `permissions`... :s